# Normalizing a Polynom

Tags: parsing, normalization, algebra, polynomials, computer-algebra-systems

I need to read in a Polynom and transform it into normalized form. 
 For example I read in `4*x * (x^2 + 4x + 3)` and it has to be transformed to `4*x^3 + 16*x^2 + 12*x`. 
Is there some tricky algorithm for it or do I have to think of something myself. I think basically this is just expanding the term. 
I am parsing the term recursively and generate a parse tree, so the normalization operations will be applied to this parse tree. 
Thanks to everybody who helps me

Comment: answer is hidden in the matrix...

Comment: There's no tricky algorithm. I'm afraid you'll have to think.

Comment: After you generate the tree, you will have to build a set of rules to modify the tree (multiply polynomials, add exponents, etc.).

Comment: As @Paul says, this is not an easy thing.

Answer (score 1):

This can be the **expression binary tree** that represents the expression `4*x * (x^2 + 4x + 3)`:

```
         *
       /    \
    *          +
  4   x      /    \
            ^        +
          x  2     /   \
                   *    3
                 4   x
```

Now you have to multiply `4x` with `x^2+4x+3`, that can end in a binary tree like this, just like we humans do:

```
                     +
                /         \ 
              +              *
          /       \        *    3   
       *             *    4 x     
     /  \           /  \        
   *     ^        *     *       
 4  x   x  2    4  x   4  x
```

Then continue multiplying numbers and `x's` adding exponents. You have to search for each operator in the tree and look for it's childs to apply the respective algebraic rules.

Hope this helps.